# While loop in snakemake; checkpoints

Tags: loops, while-loop, snakemake

One of the tools I use in snakemake can on the same data in one of the N cases return me a weird signal (non zero status) and does not record output. According to this, I want to restart this rule every time I get such a signal and get empty output. I see it as a kind of "while-cycle". I know that this kind of logic to work without an explicit DAG contradicts the idea of snakemake, but with the appearance of checkpoints, I believe that a solution can be found.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot "restart the rule", but you can run the same command multiple times.

Here is the recipe how to [mask the error](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/v5.32.0/project_info/faq.html#i-don-t-want-snakemake-to-detect-an-error-if-my-shell-command-exits-with-an-exitcode-1-what-can-i-do):

```py
shell:
    """
    set +e
    somecommand ...
    exitcode=$?
    if [ $exitcode -eq 1 ]
    then
        exit 1
    else
        exit 0
    fi
    """
```

The same approach should work with the `while` loop in bash:

```py
shell:
    """
    set +e
    somecommand ...
    exitcode=$?
    while [ $exitcode -ne 0 ]
    do
    somecommand ...
    exitcode=$?
    done
    """
```